# Historic method to produce cophasal illumination before lasers?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, laser, history, experimental-technique

In a bunch of old papers, written before lasers, the authors often refer to illumination with the same characteristics as a laser: single spatial mode and temporally lockstep.

For example in: [On the diffraction theory of optical images (H. H. Hopkins, 1953)](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/217/1130/408)

> if the object is coherently and cophasally illuminated...

What was the historic method of making this kind of illumination?

Comment: Can you link to or provide citations for any of these old papers?

Answer (score 0):

You use a bright, distant source, admitted through a pin hole; see [van Cittert–Zernike Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Cittert%E2%80%93Zernike_theorem).  Sun light works, so do certain low pressure tubes.   You can easily show interference patterns with sunlight.

This is what [Young did for his original experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_interference_experiment) which showed optical interference with sunlight.

Comment: I understand that this kind of illumination is spatially coherent, and made more so by the use of a pinhole. I don't understand why the photons march in lock step, as opposed to what Goodman would call a "thermal" source.

Comment: I remember, vaguely, the hand-waving argument of my professor: the out-of-phase elements dwindle in importance as the distance increases. The proof is in the van Cittert-Zernike theorem, which is quite detailed.